# --ignore-dependencies alternative when using bundler Gemfile

Tags: rubygems, bundler, dependency-management, gemfile

We had code before to install gems:

```
gem install rdoc --no-document --ignore-dependencies
```

But after moving to `bundler` and `Gemfile`, I don't see an option to have that `ignore-dependencies` config.

```
gem 'rdoc'
```

The problem it is creating is , [rdoc](https://rubygems.org/gems/rdoc/versions/6.4.0) has a dependency on gem  > psych , so `rdoc` downloads the latest version of `psych`. [Latest version](https://rubygems.org/gems/psych/versions/5.0.0)  (after 5.0.0) of `psych` seems to break the application.

So is there a way we can ignore dependencies when using `bundle` and `Gemfile` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psych` version 5 doesn't bundle `libyaml` which means you need to make sure you have it on your machine. If you have the option to install `libyaml-dev` please do it. It resolves the problem.

Comment: Thanks , this was it, adding `libyaml-devel` fixed it , I got my answer few days ago on the github page - https://github.com/ruby/psych/issues/600#issuecomment-1362224339